# test kitchen stuck on "creating virtual machine"

Tags: linux, chef-infra, hyper-v, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

Running `chefdk` on Windows 10 with `hyperv`.

I can use `kitchen create` to create Windows VMs and it works fine but I just tried a Linux VM and I'm getting this errror:

```
PS> kitchen create
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.10.0)
-----> Creating <default-centos-72>...
       Creating differencing disk for default-centos-72.
       Created differencing disk for default-centos-72.
       Checking for existing virtual machine.
       Creating virtual machine for default-centos-72.
       Created virtual machine for default-centos-72.

QBiA...AA== -outputformat Text ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: #< CLIXML
---- End output of c:\windows\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -encodedcommand LgAg...AA== -outputformat Text ----

ProcessId: 18780
app_name: c:\windows\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
command_line: c:\windows\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -encodedcommand LgAgAEM...BjADC0ASgBzAG8AbgAKAA== -outputformat Text
timeout: 600] on default-centos-72
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Now it does create a VM which I can manually `ssh` into via PuTTY or from cmd via openssh for Windows so I don't know why its hanging- looks like it can't access it.

This is my `.kitchen.yml`:

```
---
driver:
  name: hyperv
  parent_vhd_folder: c:\HyperV\VHDs\
  parent_vhd_name: CentOS-7.vhdx
  vm_switch: NAT
  memory_startup_bytes: 2GB

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

transport:
  password: MyPassw1!@#

platforms:
  - name: centos-7.2

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[myrecipe::default]
    attributes:
```

Edit- More info:
The server is configured for DHCP
When I look in .kitchen folder the logs are empty
**.kitche\default-centos-72.yml** only lists an id (don't know if thats supposed to have the admin name and IP in it like with rdp files?
I also tried pointing to a static IP in .kitchen.yml

Comment: Did you look at the log located at `.kitchen/logs/kitchen.log`?

Comment: Are you running the "kitchen create" in administrator mode command prompt?

Comment: Running as admin throws the same error.

Comment: The kitchen logs are emtpy

Comment: Do I have to use vagrant to access linux VMs in test kitchen? I can't actually find any examples online for accessing linux VMs directly through the hyperv driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Steven was right, should have look into to this sooner.

This looks like it might be related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1241636).

As he suggested I found Hyper-V wasn't reporting the IP on the guest and I see this:
[image]

Disabling SELinux and rebooting seems to solve this error, I can see the guest's IP in Hyper-V and kitchen create works.

Is there a way to allow this service access without completely disabling selinux?

Answer (score 2):

@red888 Does the vm have the latest guest components?  Does Hyper-V manager see the ip address associated to the vm nic?  You can check that either in hyper-v manager or via Powershell

`(get-vm 'your vm name').networkadapters[0].ipaddresses`

If it does, please file an issue at https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-hyperv and I'll be happy to dig deeper.

You'll want the latest integration components (I think 4.1 is the latest - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51612)

Comment: So CentOS7 comes with Integration Services out of the box, but I don't see the IP show up in the hyperv console or powershell. Is it supposed to or is this one of those feature linux guest don't have?

Comment: I'll try a gen 2 vm maybe

Comment: It comes with a base level of the IC, you'll need the separate more current install of the integration components. @red888

Comment: Upgraded VM with latest integration services (4.1) and still same issue.

Comment: Submitted an issue and included logs (I actually was getting logs) https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-hyperv/issues/35